# PrestaShop - eCommerce software + Git Workflow

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I was wondering if there are any PrestaShop users out there that have a good git workflow between local and production.

I would like to know if anyone has tips for log files, etc etc

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ignore the following folder and files from local.

```
 cache/   
 config/settings.inc.php
```

from the local and add all files in the git.

but the configuration changes from your local will not affect in the remote.

i am working the prestashop with git by this way only.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that ... Do you know if theres any environment flags that can be changed so that working with local and production is easier

Comment: i am using assembla git. but its paid service.

Comment: If i added an if else statement in the settings.inc.php to check for hostname, then i could switch settings based on staging, local or production ... Would that work?

Comment: Yes you can like this but what i would suggest is ignore it from git add it to the production directly only one time.

Comment: Cool, ok sorry about the questions, but how do you deal with the base uri details if your migrating the database?

Comment: you can change it from back office. because the baseuri will only work for the front office.